# Conflicting ListView Item Colouring

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles, listviewitem

Items are colored in green on mouse-over and on keyboard focused. How can i return the colouring of the selected items to white while the mouse is over some item?

it's like I have to separated mechanisms.

[image: A screenshot of the list]

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBorder" Color="Green"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush_ListItem_MO" Color="Green"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush_Tree_Item_Border" Color="Green"/>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="container">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="35"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </Grid>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource ListBorder}" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource Brush_ListItem_MO}" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource Brush_Tree_Item_Border}" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Border" Value="1" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource ListBorder}" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource Brush_ListItem_MO}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource Brush_Tree_Item_Border}" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Border" Value="1" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <!--fgdfgdfgfdgfdgfg-->
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox >
        <ListBox.Items>
            <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>4</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>5</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>        
</Grid>
```

Comment: Did an extreme overhaul, feel free to roll back if this is not what you meant, but you really should elaborate on this since your original question did not make all too much sense.

Answer (score 0):

I separated the scenarios using `MultiTrigger`. Following are the scenarios:

- Is Mouse Over and Not Selected (Green)
- Is Selected and Not Mouse OVer (Green)
- Is Mouse Over and Selected     (Light Green)

### XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBorder"
                     Color="Green" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush_ListItem_MO"
                     Color="Green" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush_Tree_Item_Border"
                     Color="Green" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush_ListItem_MO_Selected"
                     Color="LightGreen" />
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="container">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"
                                              Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                                Height="35"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                           Value="False" />
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                           Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                    TargetName="Border"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource ListBorder}" />
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    TargetName="Border"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource Brush_ListItem_MO}" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                    TargetName="Border"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource Brush_Tree_Item_Border}" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                                    TargetName="Border"
                                    Value="1" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                           Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                           Value="False" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                    TargetName="Border"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource ListBorder}" />
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    TargetName="Border"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource Brush_ListItem_MO}" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                           Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                           Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                    TargetName="Border"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource ListBorder}" />
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    TargetName="Border"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource Brush_ListItem_MO_Selected}" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected"
                                           Value="true" />
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                                           Value="false" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                    TargetName="Border"
                                    Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    TargetName="Border"
                                    Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                                    TargetName="Border"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource Brush_Tree_Item_Border}" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                                    TargetName="Border"
                                    Value="1" />
                        </MultiTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                 Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <!--fgdfgdfgfdgfdgfg-->
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.Items>
            <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>4</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>5</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks but after selecting with the mouse, if you press up/down on the keyboard you'll see that there are two green rows and I want only one.

Comment: I tried it and it only shows two green rows when one of them is selected and the other has mouse pointer over it. And that is because of Triggers we have.